# Can't display files that been uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm having a problem in displaying the files that I've uploaded in my browser.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gi7j.png

In the picture above,I manage to upload and view the files in the table for the documentation but I can't seems to do the same thing for the photos part(the one below the documentation).Here's my code in fiddle.Can anyone help me on this?Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/cr5d8znw/

```
<form name="form_id" id="form_id" action="javascript:void(0);" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:800px; margin-top:20px;">  

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label class="fieldlabels">Documentation:</label> <br>
                                    <input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files"  accept="application/pdf" multiple="multiple"/><br>  
    <!--input type="submit" value="Upload" /--><br>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:60%;" id="add_files">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Name</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
                                    <tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>


                            </div> 
                            
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <label class="fieldlabels">Photo:</label> <br>
                                    <input type="file" name="vasplus_multiple_files" id="vasplus_multiple_files" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/><br><br>        

                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:60%;" id="add_files">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Photo Name</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Status</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">File Size</th>
                                    <th style="color:blue; text-align:center;">Action</th>
                                    <tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>


                            </div> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br>
</form>
```

The first input is working perfectly but for the second input the upload is working but can't display the files that been uploaded in the tables.

Comment: The name and IDs of the inputs are the same. Not sure but maybe the form can't deal with that. IDs at least should be unique. I think form data is stored under the name attributes, so 2 of the same might not work.

Comment: I tried using different name and IDs but still can't.

Comment: @wazz Can you give a sample to solve it?