# Unexpected result on HTML file upload

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The file that I uploaded is being displayed in the wrong place.

Here's a picture of it :

[image: Error image]

When I press `Choose Files` in the `Photos` part, it displays the file name, status, file size and action, but it was displaying in the documentation table section not photos table part. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here's a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jn19cb7/).

```html
<form
  name="form_id"
  id="form_id"
  action="javascript:void(0);"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  style="width: 800px; margin-top: 20px"
>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <label class="fieldlabels">Documentation:</label> <br />
      <input
        type="file"
        name="vasplus_multiple_files"
        id="vasplus_multiple_files"
        accept="application/pdf"
        multiple="multiple"
      /><br />
      <!--input type="submit" value="Upload" /--><br />
      <table
        class="table table-striped table-bordered"
        style="width: 60%"
        id="add_files"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">File Name</th>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">Status</th>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">File Size</th>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">Action</th>
          </tr>

          <tr></tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br />
</form>

<br />

<form
  name="form_id2"
  id="form_id2"
  action="javascript:void(0);"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  style="width: 800px; margin-top: 20px"
>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <label class="fieldlabels">Photo:</label> <br />
      <input
        type="file"
        name="vasplus_multiple_files2"
        id="vasplus_multiple_files2"
        multiple="multiple"
        accept="image/*"
      /><br /><br />

      <table
        class="table table-striped table-bordered"
        style="width: 60%"
        id="add_files2"
      >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">Photo Name</th>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">Status</th>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">File Size</th>
            <th style="color: blue; text-align: center">Action</th>
          </tr>

          <tr></tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br />
</form>
```

I've tried putting 2 forms for 2 input but still not working for me.

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    $vpb_file_name = strip_tags($_FILES['upload_file']['name']); //File Name
    $vpb_file_id = strip_tags($_POST['upload_file_ids']); // File id is gotten from the file name
    $vpb_file_size = $_FILES['upload_file']['size']; // File Size
    $vpb_uploaded_files_location = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/uploads_test/'; //This is the directory where uploaded files are saved on your server
    $vpb_final_location = $vpb_uploaded_files_location . $vpb_file_name; //Directory to save file plus the file to be saved
    //Without Validation and does not save filenames in the database
    if(move_uploaded_file(strip_tags($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']), $vpb_final_location))
    {
        //Display the file id
        echo $vpb_file_id;
    }
    else
    {
        //Display general system error
        echo 'general_system_error';
    }

}
?>
```

This is my backend code.

Comment: This question is somewhat similar to [the one you posted 2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65729692/2557030), the answers there are a good start, but, to help with this one, you need to post your backend code. What is happening on the backend? The backend is generating the contents of that `<tbody>` based on the file you are uploading. A guess is that you are still using only one `name` in the backend to get the data, but it is hard to say if we can't see the code. Have a look at the [ask] page and please add a [mre].

Comment: @RaulSauco I already put my backend code in the question ..can help me check on it.

Comment: The image you sent shows a file, probably uploaded previously, under the first `<tbody></tbody>`, how is that table row generated? Where is the information about the uploaded file stored, in a database? How does your application keep track of uploaded files?

Comment: The uploaded files is stored in my folder not my database yet...the code for the table row generated is in the javascript.